# Return value in C++

Tags: c++

I am confused with the following output in C++

```
int add()
{
    int c = 2+3;
}

int main()
{
    int x = add();
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

This prints 5.even if we do not write return statement.
How this is managed in C++.
Please help.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: What compiler are you using ? I get `warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]`, and I also get 0 as value, not 5.

Comment: If I run this, I get 0.

Comment: I am using gcc compiler.

Comment: Enable more warnings on your compiler, and then have warnings treated as errors (because they usually are) and then you'll find that the problem goes away because it won't compile

Comment: Why Do You Want To Experiment Things ?Language Tells To Return Int And You Are Not Returning

Comment: @Shashank Shastri - Many times we left values from functions. If language tells us to return then language should throw an error instead of warning.

Comment: @Abhi Warnings and errors are not defined by the language. And if you want everything overseen and checked by the compiler, then C/C++ is not for you. One reason why C/C++ is this fast is because of it trusts the programmer that he knows what he is doing ( for example he won't invoke undefined behavior, if he does its his fault). If you want the compiler to help you more try python or java.

Comment: I was just testing the code while practicing some basics. I thought like name mangling and function overloading as they do not depends on return type, Here also something different.

Comment: @Abhi: I see your point re: warning vs. error, but note that it's theoretically impossible to always detect that you'll never return a value. Consider: `int f() { if (g()) { return 2; } if (h()) {return 3; } }` Should the compiler tell you there's a problem? only if it can deduce that `g() == h() == 0` is possible. This is equivalent to function comparison, which is equivalent to the halting problem.

Comment: @lorro I accept it. Thank you for clearing all my confusions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is UB. You're right to be confused - this can work one day and fail the next. Don't rely on undefined behavior.

If you want to know *why* it works, it's because parameters & return values are passed on a data structure called stack (well - usually; sometimes passed in the same register). Similarly, most implementations use this same stack for locals. Therefore, the `int` in `add` will be located in the same place as where the return value is expected (by your specific implementation) and your implementation doesn't invalidate memory when your `int` there is destructed. But it's still destructed, it's still UB and it might break in any second.

As the comments wrote, you might turn on warnings to avoid this kind of error.

Comment: it can be a register, and that will work too